# Add style to random loaded divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

It is a bit hard to explain my problem, so if I am not making my self clear, just ask.

With this script I randomly load 6 divs.

```
<script> 
$(document).ready(function(){
var divs = $("div.item").get().sort(function(){ 
return Math.round(Math.random())-0.5;
}).slice(0,6)
$(divs).show();
});
</script>
```

I am using twitter-bootstrap, and as I want 3 divs per row (two rows) I have assigned them with `.span4` class. This will I automatically generate two rows with 3 `.span4` on each. They need to align to both left- and right margin and also leave a gutter between each-one.

**[SEE HERE](http://33tpm.com/rndmspan4-ex/ex1.html)**

Now the problem is that by randomly loading them, I can not get them to align properly.
With twitter-bootstrap, the first span never gets `margin-left` whereas all the rest do.
So if I randomly load, for example:
The sixth span into the fist position and the first span into second position, then I have a alignment (margin) problem.
**[SEE HERE](http://33tpm.com/rndmspan4-ex/ex2.html)**

I figured that first I need to make all spans equal by using `.span4 { margin-left: 0 !important;}` this works fine to have the two rows neatly with the 3 `.span4` next to each-other, but then I have no gutter nor are they aligned both left and right 
**[SEE HERE](http://33tpm.com/rndmspan4-ex/ex3.html)**

I have now been struggling with this situation a few days and cannot think of any elegant solution.

Is there a Javascript solution to add style to specific spans depending in what order they are loaded?

The ones that load as first and fifth to have only a right margin

The ones loading second and fifth to have a left- and right margin

The ones loading as third and sixth to have only a left-margin

Comment: Try and create them in memory, then append to the DOM.

Comment: Thank you Kurt, could you be more specific?

Comment: What you need to do here is just remove the margin from the first and 4th div and apply a margin to all the rest. Iterate through them after you've sorted the random generation with a counter and apply margin 0 to the 1st and the 4th and however much you want to the rest. No need for left-right margin on the middle ones but a left margin on the 2nd, 3rd, 5th and 6th.

Comment: Thank you Alex, could you give me an example of the counter?

Comment: You could use an each() with a counter like you may find here http://api.jquery.com/each/ on your divs variable that holds the loaded div elements. When index is 1 and 4 you apply no margin on the $(this) in the function and for the rest you apply the left margin you need to space them out properly.

Comment: I will have to wait a couple of days to offer you a bounty, to give me a working example, as this is beyond my skills. Thnk you

Answer (score 1):

```
<script> 
$(document).ready(function(){
var divs = $("div.item").get().sort(function(){ 
return Math.round(Math.random())-0.5;
}).slice(0,6)

$(divs).each(function( index ) {
  if(index==0 || index==3)
      $(this).css("margin-left", "0px");
  else
      $(this).css("margin-left", "10px"); //or whatever left value you need
});

$(divs).show();
});
</script>
```

This should work but if divs is a weird sort of array and by chance it does not you can change the code to this.

```
<script> 
$(document).ready(function(){
var divs = $("div.item").get().sort(function(){ 
return Math.round(Math.random())-0.5;
}).slice(0,6)

var i=0;
for(i=0; i<6; i++){
  if(i==0 || i==3)
      $(divs[i]).css("margin-left", "0px");
  else
      $(divs[i]).css("margin-left", "10px"); //or whatever left value you need
}

$(divs).show();
});
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you Alex, this does something but not really.. Try refreshing a fex times and you'll see
http://33tpm.com/rndmspan4-ex/alex/ex3.html

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Alex I was able to simplify both the question and the issue so now you have two very well working answers [>> HERE <<](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19156918/add-style-to-random-loaded-divs-not-working-properly/19157398#comment28337938_19157398) 
Thank you everyone for contributing!!

Comment: Well :), I was missing a bit of content. Would have helped to see the html code as I did not know whether show was extended or not or how the divs were positioned in the DOM. Happy to see you've managed to sort it out.