# Add style to random loaded divs - Not working properly

Tags: javascript, css

This a continued question from this post:
[Add style to random loaded divs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19152522/add-style-to-random-loaded-divs) I have now tried to simplify this question as much as possible.

Here goes:

Using this code I am trying to add style to randomly loaded items depending in what order they are loaded.

```
<script> 
$(document).ready(function(){
var divs = $("div.item").get().sort(function(){ 
return Math.round(Math.random())-0.5;
}).slice(0,6)

$(divs).each(function( index ) {
if(index==1 || index==3)
$(this).css("margin-left", "0%");
else
$(this).css("margin-left", "2%"); //or whatever left value you need
});
$(divs).show(); 
}); 
</script>
```

I need the `.item` bars to line up as in this picture
[image]
So far this only ocurs by chance every so many times you refresh the browser.

I think if you try it yourself you'll see what the problem 
Here is the whole shebang for a quick copy/paste

```
    <html>
    <head>


    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.js"></script>

    <style>
    .container {width:750px; background-color:#CCC; height:200px; padding-top:70px; margin: 0 auto; margin-top:5%}
    .item {display:none; text-align:center; width:32%; float:left}
    </style>    

    <script> 
    $(document).ready(function(){
    var divs = $("div.item").get().sort(function(){ 
    return Math.round(Math.random())-0.5;
    }).slice(0,6)

    $(divs).each(function( index ) {
      if(index==1 || index==3)
          $(this).css("margin-left", "0%");
      else
          $(this).css("margin-left", "2%"); //or whatever left value you need
    });
    $(divs).show();
    });
    </script>

    </head>

    <body>    

         <div class="container">
          <div class="item" style="background-color:#F00">1</div>
          <div class="item" style="background-color:#9F0">2</div>
          <div class="item" style="background-color:#FF0">3</div>

          <div class="item" style="background-color:#939">4</div>
          <div class="item" style="background-color:#3CF">5</div> 
          <div class="item" style="background-color:#CF3">6</div> 

          <div class="item" style="background-color:#6C9">7</div>
          <div class="item" style="background-color:#999">8</div> 
          <div class="item" style="background-color:#90F">9</div> 

          <div class="item" style="background-color:#FF9">10</div>
          <div class="item" style="background-color:#099">11</div>
          <div class="item" style="background-color:#666">12</div>

          </div>



    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because the divs you are looping over won't always match the order of your divs in markup, which means you'll be applying the wrong margins.  Try the code below:

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.js"></script>
    <style>
        .container {width:750px; background-color:#CCC; height:200px; padding-top:70px; margin: 0 auto; margin-top:5%}
        .item {display:none; text-align:center; width:32%; float:left}
    </style>    

    <script>        
        $(document).ready(function(){
            var $container = $('div.container'),
                divs = $("div.item").get().sort(function(){ 
                    return Math.round(Math.random())-0.5;
                }).slice(0,6),

                <!-- Make a clone, leaving original pot untouched -->
                $clonedDivs = $(divs).clone();


            <!-- Clear container -->
            $container.html('');

            <!-- Append new divs to container  -->
            $clonedDivs.each(function( index ) {
                $container.append(this);

                if (index % 3 == 0) {
                  $(this).css("margin-left", "0%");
                } else {
                  $(this).css("margin-left", "2%"); //or whatever left value you need
                }
            });

            $clonedDivs.show();
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>  
    <div class="pot">
      <div class="item" style="background-color:#F00">1</div>
      <div class="item" style="background-color:#9F0">2</div>
      <div class="item" style="background-color:#FF0">3</div>

      <div class="item" style="background-color:#939">4</div>
      <div class="item" style="background-color:#3CF">5</div> 
      <div class="item" style="background-color:#CF3">6</div> 

      <div class="item" style="background-color:#6C9">7</div>
      <div class="item" style="background-color:#999">8</div> 
      <div class="item" style="background-color:#90F">9</div> 

      <div class="item" style="background-color:#FF9">10</div>
      <div class="item" style="background-color:#099">11</div>
      <div class="item" style="background-color:#666">12</div>      
    </div>

    <div class="container">
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: also, is it possible to load the div.item's from an external html?

Answer (score 2):

Because you are not randomizing the DOM **order**, only what divs to include in the `divs` array. The order is still numerical.

So when looping the `divs` using `$.each(divs)`, you are looping the random order you created, but the DOM order is still untouched (if that makes sense). You could say that `divs` and `$('div.items')` are out of sync.

You can try this instead: (DEMO: http://jsbin.com/aSejiWA/3)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var divs = $("div.item").get().sort(function(){ 
        return Math.round(Math.random())-0.5;
    }).slice(0,6);

    $(divs).addClass('show'); // to re-select the visual items

    $('.item.show').each(function( index ) {
      $(this).css('margin-left', index%3 ? '2%' : 0); 
    }).show();
});
```